# Typescript shows an error even though it compiles on VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, react-redux

I'm using react-redux with typescript and when I define a reducer inside a Slice VSCode shows this error even though it compiles and everything works.

[image: Error message]

Here's the full code:

```js
//counterSlice.ts

import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export interface CounterState {
  value: number
}

const initialState: CounterState = {
  value: 0
}

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    }
  }
})

export const { incrementByAmount } = counterSlice.actions

export default counterSlice.reducer
```

Comment: Maybe restart your editor?

Comment: @phry Already restarted both editor and computer.

Comment: The code looks valid as far as I can see. (In fact, it looks to be straight out of our RTK+TS CRA template.)  What happens if you put this into a CodeSandbox?

Comment: @markerikson It works on CodeSandbox and it even works on another computer so I suppose it's something related to VSCode installed on my computer but I discovered that VSCode has no cache so I'm wondering what could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

Reinstalling the packages with `npm` solved the problem.